# In magento 1.9.0.0 how can I Enable template path Hint?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I am trying to turn on template path hint in magento 1.9.0.0 but it's not working.

But in magento 1.8.0.0 it's fully working. How can I turn it on in magento 1.9?
[image]

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I see that you have selected store view, Main Website. Please select website view e.g. English and enable template path.

Comment: You have it the other way around, he has selected a Website, instead of a Store View. The overall story is correct, it's probably overridden on a lower (store view) level.

Comment: Problem solved. I select english store view. But in magento 1.8.0.0 I am always select main website then also template path hint is displayed. bt in magento 1.9.0.0 it will not displayed with the selecting main website.

Comment: where the heck are those things you're talking about?

Answer (score 6):

I haven't installed any language (default was English). For me it works (for version 1.9.2) when I choose "Current Configuration Scope:" -> "Default Store View". Check a screenshot below: [image: Magento configuration scope]

Answer (score 3):

To enable template path hints follow the following steps:

1. Go to Magento admin panel->systems->configuration
2. Choose your store view on top left corner in Current Configuration Scope ex:english
3. Go to Advanced tab. Under that click on Developer->Debug. If you want both block and view template path hints, click yes on Template path hints (phtml files) and Add Block Names to Hints.
4. Refresh your frontend
5. List item

Comment: Thanks for answer, but this is one year old question. And I also changed my language. Now I am android Developer not Magento. :)