# Magento Checkout Page escaping HTML tags

Tags: php, magento, checkout, html-escape

I've given some HTML in the custom options of Magento, it is working perfectly fine on the product page however in the checkout page, it is showing with HTML code. When I checked the source code, the HTML tags has been converted to entities. For example, `<span>` is showing like this `&lt;span&gt;`.

```
<dl class="item-options">
    <?php foreach ($_options as $_option) : ?>
    <?php $_formatedOptionValue = $this->getFormatedOptionValue($_option) ?>
    <dt><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_option['label']) ?></dt>
    <dd<?php if (isset($_formatedOptionValue['full_view'])): ?> class="truncated"<?php endif; ?>><?php echo $_formatedOptionValue['value'] ?>
        <?php if (isset($_formatedOptionValue['full_view'])): ?>
        <div class="truncated_full_value">
            <dl class="item-options">
                <dt><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_option['label']) ?></dt>
                <dd><?php echo $_formatedOptionValue['full_view'] ?></dd>
            </dl>
```

I'm thinking that `$this->htmlEscape` has something to do with this mess? Anyone knows how to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried removing it? from `htmlEscape($_option['label'])` to `$_option['label']`

Comment: yeah, it doesn't work for me

Comment: Just looking at some articles, it seems `htmlEscape` is a deprecated function on megento, try using `escapeHtml` and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: nopes, it is same as before..

Comment: Use [template path hints](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24273443/471559) to make sure you definitely are editing the correct file.  And disable the cache whenever you are developing.

Comment: Thanks clockworkgeek for your suggestion. I've checked from template path hints point of view as well and it is showing me the same file which I'm editing i.e. `frontend/default/gadget/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml`

Comment: can anyone help me with regards to my issue?