# The Shopping cart and the product view page in magento

Tags: magento

I know the location of the prouduct page is **view.phtml** and calculate price in **/varien/Product.js**, **Abstract.php** for custom option prices' labels. (I had made some modifcation for these files)

But what about the shopping cart's? i know **default.phtml** is about the frontend and get price from **Data.php** but what about the custom option values? Does it reload the price like **Product.js**?

I want to standardize the prices in my magento but they having different custom option price.

So for example consider i have offer a half price discount for the product so  (karat tone : 18k +37.5$) in my product page but (Karat tone : 18k +70$) appear in my shopping cart (no discount)
**The product price is fine in my case, only the custom option has problem**

You only need to tell me where does the custom option of the shopping cart local.

[image] [image]

None of these paths helps i presume its in the backend, inside mage or so observer file.
[image]

Comment: Hint: To know which template file is used, you can turn on Template Path Hints. Read more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24273443/in-magento-1-9-0-0-how-can-i-enable-template-path-hint). Make sure you do not overwrite the base files. Use override instead.

Comment: yes i tried it, it only tells your the frontend section

Comment: I would suggest using https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_TemplateHints to enhance the template hints.