# In Magento 1.9.01 Enable Debug Hint Not Working

Tags: magento, debugging, hint

I've tried to follow the steps listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24273443/in-magento-1-9-0-0-how-can-i-enable-template-path-hint). I selected `yes` for all stores, but it's still not working. Hints do not show up at front end.

Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

You can also enable the template path hints from the db.
Below is the sql query

```
UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value` = 1 WHERE `path` LIKE '%hints%';
```

Comment: Thank to this :http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3615/template-path-not-showing. i made empty this field (developer client restrictions)...