# Magento product page error code

Tags: php, xml, magento-1.9

I added a new product and it shows fine but if i add an image to the product then i get this code on the Frontend anyone here to help me
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: are you refering about the "This is a demo store...." message or the display of template codes?

Comment: no i am refering tags @manian

Comment: You might have enabled the template path hints, please check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/37434675/4874281