# Change Out of Stock to symbol

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

When my product is out of stock it just displays the words "out of stock".
Everything else is little symbols, so this doesn't match the theme.
I would like to display a greyed out cart symbol instead.
How would I do this?

[The display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmuAq.png)

Comment: use magento template path hints, then find from which file : `out of stock` text displaying, there add the `greyed out cart symbol icon`....

Comment: how do i use path hints in magento 1.9?

Comment: see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24273443/in-magento-1-9-0-0-how-can-i-enable-template-path-hint)